# Oauth2 Client Credentials Flow + Spring Boot2 throwing There is no PasswordEncoder mapped > for the for the id "null" error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am upgrading my existing Client Credentials Oauth2 to use spring boot 2.
The Authorization Server uses Basic Auth with *Base64* encoding of `(client:secret)`
I am using *RedisTokenStore* to store the tokens. 
I am struggling with the configuration required for Oauth2 configuration with the new upgrade. I could not find a proper documentation that points me to Client Credentials flow.

With updates to Spring 5 Security the password encoding is failing, I am getting :-

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped
>   for the id "null" error

Following is my configuration:-

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.
                        csrf().disable().
                        authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll();
        }

}
```

*AuthorizationServer* and *ResourceServer*

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class Oauth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnFactory;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore());
        super.configure(endpoints);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        String idForEncode = "bcrypt";
        Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoderMap = new HashMap<>();
        encoderMap.put(idForEncode, new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(idForEncode, encoderMap);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new Oauth2TokenStore(jedisConnFactory);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/verify_token").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/info").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/health").permitAll();
        }
    }
}
```

*RedisTokenStore*

```
public class Oauth2TokenStore extends RedisTokenStore {
    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;


    public Oauth2TokenStore(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        super(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public void storeAccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken token, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();

        //Principal is consumer key since we only support client credential flow
        String consumerKey = (String) principal;

        //get client detials
        ClientDetails clientDetails = clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(consumerKey);


        // Logic to Create JWT
        .
        .
        .
        //Set it to Authentication
        authentication.setDetails(authToken);

       super.storeAccessToken(token, authentication);
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication readAuthentication(String token) {
        OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication =  super.readAuthentication(token);
        if (oAuth2Authentication == null) {
            throw new InvalidTokenException("Access token expired");
        }
        return oAuth2Authentication;
    }
}
}
```

Also do I need to encode the token when I am storing in the redis store after the updates to spring security password encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that the password stored isn't prefixed with the password type.

For example, your hashed passwords might look something like:

```
$2a$10$betZ1XaM8rTUQHwWS.cyIeTKJySBfZsmC3AYxYjwa4fHtr6i/.9oG
```

But, Spring Security is now expecting:

```
{bcrypt}$2a$10$betZ1XaM8rTUQHwWS.cyIeTKJySBfZsmC3AYxYjwa4fHtr6i/.9oG
```

You basically have [two options](https://info.michael-simons.eu/2018/01/13/spring-security-5-new-password-storage-format/). The first is to configure your `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` with what should be the default:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    String idForEncode = "bcrypt";
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoderMap = 
        Collections.singletonMap(idForEncode, bcrypt);
    DelegatingPasswordEncoder delegating =
        new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(idForEncode, encoderMap);
    delegating.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(bcrypt);
    return delegating;
}
```

Or the second is to do a batch upgrade of your password store (prefixing them with `{bcrypt}`).

I'm not certain what your `ClientDetailsService` is pulling from, but I would begin looking there.

**UPDATE**: This assumes, though, that your existing passwords are bcrypted. If they aren't, then you'd supply whatever the appropriate encoder is:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    String idForEncode = "bcrypt";
    PasswordEncoder existing = new MyPasswordEncoder();
    PasswordEncoder updated = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoderMap = 
        Collections.singletonMap(idForEncode, updated);
    DelegatingPasswordEncoder delegating =
        new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(idForEncode, encoderMap);
    delegating.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(existing);
    return delegating;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help the clientId and secret are generated by other service which is not part of this application and its a public facing API hence we need to share the clientId and secret in plaintext with the requesting application. I think you are right i need to change the store to append _{bcrypt}_, I could not get it running with the PasswordEncoder that you shared it says `Encoded password does not look like BCrypt`, I tried NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance() and got it running.

Comment: What is the hash you are using for your passwords? The error means that the encoder thinks it isn't bcrypt.

Comment: I am storing it plaintext, there is no hash on client key or client secret, the format is `Base64 encode of client:secret`

Comment: prior to the upgrade it was using PlaintextPasswordEncoder.

Comment: So, then why not just return an instance of PlaintextPasswordEncoder, OOC?

Comment: I cant since its not a part of spring 5 anymore.